# RecyclerView behavior_overlapTop without parent resize

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overlap, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with a `RecyclerView` to show some movie details. I've set `behavior_overlapTop="40dp"` to show the movie's poster over the background image. Everything works good but when scrolling there is a small part of the gray background that get resized to fill the gap between `RecyclerView` and `Toolbar`, as you can see in the image:

[image]

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_behavior="com.est.streamcorn.ui.customs.FixAppBarLayoutBehavior">

        <com.est.streamcorn.ui.customs.widgets.CustomCollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:scrimAnimationDuration="250"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/trailer_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/trailer_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/trailer_button_background"
                    android:drawablePadding="10.0dip"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:minHeight="40.0dip"
                    android:paddingEnd="25.0dip"
                    android:paddingStart="20.0dip"
                    android:text="@string/trailer"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15.0sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    tools:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.est.streamcorn.ui.customs.widgets.CustomCollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="40dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is there a way to disable this? Or at least to change the color to white?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you find solution?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Have you or anyone else found a solution?

Comment: I didn't find a way to keep the expanding part transparent, by I managed to make it white by simply using a custom window's background with two colors, with the top part white and the bottom part grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution to keep the expanding part transparent, by I found a workaround to make it white by simply using a custom window's background with two colors: the top part white and the bottom part grey.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that thin dark line that appears as you start to open up the app bar? That is the toolbar's elevation. To turn it off, add the following to the toolbar XML:

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

You can also manipulate the elevation programmatically with [`setElevation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setElevation(float)). This might be useful if you want the elevation shadow to be present some times but not others.

Comment: No sorry, I mean the grey part that appear between the white rectangle and the above image.